# Dynamically construct a return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am creating a module where other developers can create a datamodel with (for me) unknown properties and types. Only a limited set of types is supported. The datamodel argument is an object with property names as keys and the values are config objects containing the type (as a string) and some other options. I want the function to return a typesafe object based on the datamodel with full Intellisense. I know I can use generics and make the calling code define a type and then return it, but I would not be able to accept other options in an intuitive way. Is it possible to "construct the type dynamically" based on the datamodel without generics? Or is there a smart way of using generics to actually accept an object like this but transform it to match the wanted return type?

Example code:

```
//Module function
function createDynamicReturnType(datamodel: { [key:string]: { type: 
   'string'|'number'|'boolean', someOption: boolean } }) : {[key:string]: string|number|boolean } {
    const typesafeModelObject = {};
    //iterate datamodel keys and map the correct type from the type string
    //'string' -> type string
    //'number' -> type number
    //'boolean' -> type boolean

    //someOption on the properties is used for something but not interesting to return

    return typesafeModelObject;
}

//Usage
const typesafePerson = createDynamicReturnType({
    name: { type: 'string', someOption: true, },
    registered: { type: 'boolean', someOption: false, },
    age: { type: 'number', someOption: true, },
});

//Wanted result
//typesafePerson has correct types and Intellisense
//typesafePerson.name -> string
//typesafePerson.registered -> boolean
//typesafePerson.age -> number
```

Comment: What does `someOption` do? Does it have any effect on the returned result?

Comment: Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9nJJm) maybe?  Your stipulation about not using generics unless it's "smart" is confusing me.  But if that approach works I could write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please mention @jcalz so I'm notified)

Comment: @caTS The someOption property is used inside the function but is not interesting to keep on the returned type (added a code comment to point that out)

Comment: You might be better off using something like io-ts.

Comment: @jcalz Your answer is exactly what I need. I missed that the generic function can be called without <thetype> in front and still work by infering the type from the argument. That way the function usage can be exactly the same as the example but also with the generic typing and return type needed.

Comment: Okay I can write up an answer when I get the chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make `createDynamicReturnType()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in an object type `T` corresponding to the keys and `type` properties of `datamodel`.  And then you can use a mapping interface to look up the desired output type for a given `type`.  It could look like this:

```
interface TypeMap {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    boolean: boolean;
}

declare function createDynamicReturnType<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof TypeMap>>(
    datamodel: { [K in keyof T]: { type: T[K], someOption: boolean } }
): { [K in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[K]] };
```

The `TypeMap` interface is a mapping from the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `type` properties: namely, `"string"`, `"number"`, and `"boolean"`, to the corresponding output property types: namely, `string`, `number`, and `boolean`, respectively.

Then `createDynamicReturnType()` accepts `datamodel` of [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[K in keyof T]: {type: T[K], someOption: boolean}}`.  The compiler is able to infer `T` from such a mapped type.  So if you pass in, say, `{foo: {type: "string", someOption: false}}`, the compiler will understand that `T` must be `{foo: "string"}`.  Note that `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof T, keyof TypeMap>`, meaning that it can have any keys, but its properties (`T[K]` for every `K` in `keyof T`) must be chosen from the keys of `TypeMap` (which is `"string" | "number" | "boolean"`).

Finally, the return type is another mapped type, this type `{[K in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[K]] }`.  The type `TypeMap[T[K]]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), meaning that for each key `K` from `T`, we look up the property of `TypeMap` whose key is `T[K]`.  For example, if `T` is `{foo: "string"}`, then when `K` is `"foo"`, `T[K]` is `"string"`, and `TypeMap[T[K]]` is `TypeMap["string"]` which is `string`, so the output type is `{foo: string}`.

---

Let's try it out:

```
//Usage
const typesafePerson = createDynamicReturnType({
    name: { type: 'string', someOption: true, },
    registered: { type: 'boolean', someOption: false, },
    age: { type: 'number', someOption: true, },
});

/* const typesafePerson: {
    name: string;
    registered: boolean;
    age: number;
} */
```

Looks good.  In that call, the compiler has inferred `T` to be `{name: "string", registered: "boolean", age: "number"}`, and therefore the output type is `{name: string, registered: boolean, age: number}`, as desired.

---

There are other ways to accomplish the same goal; for example, you *could* make the function generic in `T` corresponding *exactly* to the `datamodel` parameter, and then compute the output type from it.  That could look like, say, this:

```
declare function createDynamicReturnType<
    T extends Record<keyof T, { type: keyof TypeMap, someOption: boolean }>>(
        datamodel: T
    ): { [K in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[K]['type']] };
```

It's similar, but here you have to constrain `T` to the shape you want `datamodel` to have, and then you need to look up `T[K]['type']` in `TypeMap`.  It behaves the same when you call it:

```
const typesafePerson = createDynamicReturnType({
    name: { type: 'string', someOption: true, },
    registered: { type: 'boolean', someOption: false, },
    age: { type: 'number', someOption: true, },
});

/* const typesafePerson: {
    name: string;
    registered: boolean;
    age: number;
} */
```

it's just that now `T` is inferred to be the exact type of `dataModel`, with all the `type` and `someOption` properties.

---

The exact approach you use is up to you, and that decision possibly depends on factors outside this question.

In any case, you'll probably need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or other type safety loosening technique inside the *implementation* of `createDynamicReturnType` because it is unlikely that the compiler will be able to verify that the value you return is of type `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` for generic `T`.  But again, that is outside the scope of the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-i1+LMhJiJKSKTSWwyotI2TyBSKJTc5UqSw6LTNW3El+bXRgHPtPInKpuvQGRpcIzAYwgEyNPuJCPPSzwUK87SrDs3xcH8ezTEy5pMoCwIziQ4JQia8L+pQDLQCAaKYjQ2JIHioRrhAUQbgkW7klslLAYOtJyreiodraGoOqGzr6sKTFxlKiasQqSpjuYnEvo6SA6nqrpMRm9LmsyQ6SVy3G8rx8l8PYHroUgPp+oieGBoRwYkaGtZ6BG4gdiOJCCQmMpvqmCmwpm2jDoMub5vYQA)

Comment: I’m impressed, very good answer. Thank you! @jcalz